# How to create custom uitableview like that

Tags: iphone, ipad

I want to create uitableview like the following , also I need to add a third section that contains rows [image]

any suggestion please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do all of this in an UITableViewController with -

```
 UITableViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDataSource -
```

For Patient & ACC => Set a UITextField as a Subview (Do this in the cellForRowAtIndexPath for their respective rows)

For Birth and Date => Use the UIDatePickerView and for row ==2 and row ==4 respectively.

For Modality => I do not know what you mean by that; But you need to do something similar

For getting another section for the other two values; Return Section = 2 in

```
(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
```

and set title for those accordingly (if needed)

Code :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110, 10, 185, 30)];

    textField.clearsOnBeginEditing = YES;
    textField.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
    textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
    textField.delegate = self;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:textField];

    if (indexPath.row == 2)
    {
        UIDatePicker *datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
        datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
        [datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(datePickerValueChangedd:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        datePicker.tag = indexPath.row;
        textField.inputView = datePicker;

        NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        df.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterMediumStyle;
        NSString *local;
        local = [self datePickerValueChangedd: datePicker];  
        NSLog(@"%@", local);
        textField.text =local;
        [datePicker reloadInputViews];
        [datePicker release];

    }
}

// Configure the cell...

NSInteger row = [indexPath row];
cell.textLabel.text = [doseInfoDetailsArray objectAtIndex:row];

return cell;
```

}

Comment: So... Was it useful ? I have one more suggestion. Use the datePicker methods in the textFieldDidBeginEditing. You can set the date with the value in the PickerView.

Comment: @Legolas if u could give me complete project because I am get stuck with the section I want to add the will be the rows returned depending on the value on textfields

Comment: Could you be specific what you mean by 'Complete Project' ?

Comment: I mean sample project with sections , if ur tiem allow I need two sections and button when clikc on it use the informations in the two sections to fill third one with rows

Comment: Is it not the whole View ?? StacK OverFlow is foe just clearing doubts. It's not for making a complete project.

Comment: I see. I am sure you will get it eventually. Try solving things in small steps and post small questions. We all love to help. If you are satisfied with the the solution I had provided... could you please give it a Tick and accept it ?

Comment: how after type in the textfield I can return the inserted value , for modality I need to have a textbox within it a button when click on it a subview opened to select from it ,and when return the selected value be added to the

Answer (score 0):

You can take UITableview with style "Group" and can have 3 sections.